# C# How do I find how many children a process has from a process id?

Tags: c#, .net

I have looked for ways to do this, however only found on how to kill the entire process tree of a parent and I could not understand how to get the children of a process. I need to find the amount of children a process has, and if it has 0 then not run my code.

Comment: I am quite new to c# by the way.

Comment: If by "children" you mean "threads" you can use `Process.Threads`